# setting up a 2nd web2py app on a separate domain in PythonAnywhere

Tags: web2py, pythonanywhere

I've just added one more web2py app on PythonAnywhere. I understand that if I want it to run under a different URL (i.e. on its own URL, in relevance to the 1st app already installed), I need to setup a new webapp in PA.

It asked me about web2py directory, prompting with the default directory where I already have web2py.

This is what is not clear to me: should I have a 2nd installation of web2py in a different directory? (i.e. each app with its own URL needs a new web2py installation)? Or I can somehow have them all under one web2py installation, and there is no need to install a new one with each new app?

How many web2py installs and consequently how many web2py folders I need is something that is not clear from the help docs.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the relevant PythonAnywhere help page:

> It is possible to set up multiple domains on PythonAnywhere, which all
>   talk to a single web2py installation, which then has multiple web2py
>   applications for each domain. Then you can set up all the web2py apps
>   you want via the web2py interface.
>
> Start by setting up one domain with the web2py wizard on the
>   PythonAnywhere web tab.
>
> Then, for each additional domain name, you need to set up another
>   PythonAnywhere web app from the web tab. This time though, you should
>   choose "manual configuration". Then, go and edit your WSGI file. You
>   should make it into a copy of the WSGI file for the first web2py
>   application, so that both domains point at the same web2py
>   installation. Then the web2py routes.py should work.

See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MultipleDomainsWeb2py/

Comment: Oh, I missed that "manual configuration" - thank you!
But just one quick question - what's that "edit your WSGI file"? I vaguely have an idea what WSGI is, but have never worked with those -

Comment: The wsgi file is the file that PythonAnywhere reads and runs and then uses to create uWSGI web workers to respond and process incoming web requests. You can find your wsgi file under the PythonAnywhere web tab for your website- clicking on it will take you to edit it. You will find sample code/comments for how to configure it within that file.